# Automatic Login a website with out click submit using java application

Tags: java, javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to open two websites in my Application. Those websites having the login form with action in POST method.

My requirement is to redirect to after login page of those website, when I hit in my project.

Where I know username and password
One website code having in PHP, where login form having fields

```html
<form action="login.php" method="post" id="clientLogin">
    <input type="hidden" name="__CSRFToken__" value="eac035fe0a1a64a9945e0ce798a44a52ca040b5c" /><div style="display:table-row">
    <div class="login-box">
    <strong></strong>
    <div>
        <input id="username" placeholder="Email or Username" type="text" name="luser" size="30" value="">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input id="passwd" placeholder="Password" type="password" name="lpasswd" size="30" value=""></td>
    </div>
    <p>
        <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Sign In">
    </p>
    </div>
    <div style="display:table-cell;padding: 15px;vertical-align:top">
    <div>
<!--<b>I'm an agent</b> —
 <a href="/scp/">sign in here</a>
 -->
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

for this site I should automatically login and display next page.

I tried [this with URLConnection](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-automate-login-a-website-java-example/) but it is redirecting to the home page of website.

How do I do that?

Comment: Why don't you show us the code of what you tried?

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like you are trying to do something similar to what a phishing site might do. There are a lot of browser and site protections to prevent such attack vectors, so you might be running across this?

Answer (score 0):

In my personal experience, i cant do it simultaneous log in with two system. what i do is the user first have to select what system the user what to log in using your app.

to do this, first create two php files; copy the log-in form of two website you wish to log(in each file). Using javascript and iframe you will change the login form depending on what the user will select and then that. the user can now login with different website using your app.